# Create log in Tomcat from War

Tags: java, file, tomcat, logging

I want to create a log file for each war I have in my tomcat.
In local with Windows works perfectly, but in my tomcat, doesn't create the file, and the path is correct.

```
public static Logger logApp = Logger.getLogger(ENTORNO + LOW_BAR + "LOG");

private static void setLogger() {
    try {
        /// CONFIGURACIÓN DE LOG ///
        FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("///opt/tomcat/Firebase/" + ENTORNO + LOW_BAR + "LOG" + ".log");
        logApp.addHandler(fh);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);
    } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {
        EmailSenderService.sendMail("El seteo del log ha fallado: " + e.getMessage(), ERROR);
    }
}
```

Doesn't throw any exception, but don't create the file.
What I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try log4j[[1](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html)] kind of solution for logging. In that case, you don't have to implement anything. You can import the log4j jar into the web app and create a log4j configuration for each web app to have a different log file.

Sample log4j configuration

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Appender1,Appender2

log4j.appender.Appender1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=C:\\webapp1.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
```

Comment: And, can you give me an example of log4j configuration? I want to say, log4j.properties

Comment: Updated with a sample log4j configuration. Have a look at https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example which is a complete example.